# jquery cheerio going over an array of elements

Tags: jquery, html, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to go over elements of 2 html tables:

```
<table class="content">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>head1</th>
            <td>value1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>head2</th>
            <td>value2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="content">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>alpha1</th>
            <td>value4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>alpha2</th>
            <td>value5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>alpha3</th>
            <td>value6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Using jquery selectors or cheerio, i'm trying to collect these elements and put them in a JSON object where the  text elements would go as keys and the  as values so it would looke like this

```
{head1: 'value1',head2: 'value2', alpha1: 'value4', alpha2: 'value5', alpha3: 'value6'}
```

I was trying along the lines of

```
$('.content).map(function(i, el) {el=$(el).find('>th').text(); return el;}).get().join(',');
```

but it seems to give me 2 objects because of the 2 tables of the same name. Help appreciated, thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To produce JSON with the structure:

```
[{"head1": "value1"},{"head2": "value2"},{"alpha1": "value4"},{"alpha2": "value5"}, {"alpha3": "value6"}]
```

Iterate over the table rows and push objects into an array:

```
function createJSON(){
    var self = this;
    self.thejson = [];
    $('.content tr').each(function(index, value){
        var k = $('th', this).text(), v = $('td', this).text();
        var data = {};
        data[k] = v;
        self.thejson.push(data);
    });
    return self.thejson;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yEJPg/

EDIT: The op initially specified the required JSON as an array of objects, but has since updated it to the following structure:

```
{
    "head1": "value1",
    "head2": "value2",
    "alpha1": "value4",
    "alpha2": "value5",
    "alpha3": "value6"
}
```

The idea is the same, but this time we add the data to an object instead of adding objects to an array:

```
function createJSON(){
    var self = this;
    self.thejson = {};
    $('.content tr').each(function(index, value){
        var k = $('th', this).text(), v = $('td', this).text();
        self.thejson[k] = v;
    });
    return self.thejson;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/waTQJ/

Comment: Thanks @mathewbergt Your answer is correct, my biggest mistake was to try to use .map when .each was relevant jQuery function however I realised I made a mistake in my question, the JSON object was not correctly described, if you could amend your answer accordingly, sorry!